# flutter yield does not work for same class in NavigationEvents

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, yield

I am trying to use the drawer to navigate (yield) to the same class (CategoryListPage) with different parameters it doesnt seem to update the widget page.

but if I go HomePage then yield CategoryListPage(), it works.

What can I do to navigate to the same class, is there a way to refresh the content ?

here is my code:

```
class NavigationBloc extends Bloc<NavigationEvents, NavigationStates> {
  @override
  NavigationStates get initialState => HomePage();

  @override
  Stream<NavigationStates> mapEventToState(NavigationEvents event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case NavigationEvents.HomePageClickedEvent:
        yield HomePage();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.ClickedEvent1:
        yield CategoryListPage(languageObjectList.list_1, languageCategoryList.languagecategorylist[1-1].category_name);
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.ClickedEvent2:
        yield CategoryListPage(languageObjectList.list_2, languageCategoryList.languagecategorylist[2-1].category_name);
        break;
```

some more code here:

```
class CategoryListPage extends StatefulWidget with NavigationStates {
...
```

class CategoryListPage extends StatefulWidget with NavigationStates {

List _languagelistcategorydata;
  String _titleappbar;

CategoryListPage(List languagelistcategorydata, String titleappbar) {
    _languagelistcategorydata = languagelistcategorydata;
    _titleappbar = titleappbar;
  }

here is the next page it is trying to yield(display). its a listview page.

```
class CategoryListPage extends StatefulWidget with NavigationStates {

  List<LanguageObject> _languagelistcategorydata;
  String _titleappbar;    

  CategoryListPage(List<LanguageObject> languagelistcategorydata, String titleappbar) {
    _languagelistcategorydata = languagelistcategorydata;
    _titleappbar = titleappbar;
  }
      @override
      _CategoryListPageState createState() => _CategoryListPageState(_languagelistcategorydata, _titleappbar);
    }

    class _CategoryListPageState extends State<CategoryListPage> {
      List<LanguageObject> items;
      String titleappbar;

  _CategoryListPageState(List<LanguageObject> languagelistcategorydata, String titleappbar) {
    this.items = languagelistcategorydata;
    this.titleappbar = titleappbar;
  }
```

Comment: it throws any errors or silently does nothing ?

Comment: This post seems similar to your question [Flutter BloC not refresh my view (counter app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676874/flutter-bloc-not-refresh-my-view-counter-app) . Check the second answer.

Comment: looks similar but I am still unsure how to solve it. I tried this https://dpaste.org/7uxO

Comment: One idea I have is to have 2 different CategoryListPage (eg: CategoryListPageOne and CategoryListPageTwo). But Im not sure how to check/save the currentState NavigationStates to know which is current and then issue a yield on a different CategoryListPage

Answer (score 1):

In your Bloc, you might have defined the Events and States class.

Are you implementing `equatable`?

You need to define how you want to compare the two same states that might be coming in.

For example, you can have a State Class called `DisplayData()` but if you will yield DisplayData() again and again, the UI might not refresh as it just checks that the last state type is DisplayData and the new state is also DisplayData hence no changes are there.

With equatable package, you specify how to compare two same State classes.

```
    class DisplayData extends Equatable {
      String data;
      DisplayData(this.data);

      // This is what you need to add, here you specify what fields of this state class needs to be checked for equality.
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [data];
    }
```

The equatable is equivalent of the Comparator class in Java.

Comment: Thanks. I still have trouble figuring this out. I understand what is Equatable, compare class functionality. How can I extend Equatable to my NavigationStates class. Its currently declared like below.

Comment: class CategoryListPage extends StatefulWidget with NavigationStates {

Comment: use a mixin ? EquatableMixin ?